# Can two different apps use the same Push SSL Certificate?

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

I'm configuring stuff on the provisioning portal for a new app which will use APNS.

When I went to configure the App Id for pushes the web site popped up a dialog saying I had to use Keychain Access and request a certificate from a CA.
However this is a step I've already been through with a previous app, therefore is there any need to do so again? If there's no need, is it still a good idea, and if so why?

If there's no need to generate a CSR again, then I no longer have the CSR file from previously, so is there anyway to recover it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certificates belong to hostnames.

If the hostname is the same, yes you can.
If it is a subdomain, and the certificate is a wildcard, yes you can.

If the hostname is different, you can generate a new csr and apply for your new certificate.